# Dark mode issues in iPhone 6s running iOS 13.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, display, whatsapp.app, dark-mode

Until yesterday, the Dark Mode on my iPhone was fine. But, I don’t know what happened to it just now.

I’m talking about using it on WhatsApp and Settings app (only minor change in settings app).

An earlier look at sent messages and you will see a bit darker shade of green.

[image: Focus on that sent msgs (You will see a bit darker shade of green)]

Now the green color has a white shade in it too!

[image: Here the green color has white shade in it too!]

I even contacted Apple support but they weren’t able to suggest the solution and told me to reset the device!

I did it but it's still the same.

Any suggestions to get the original dark coloring back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled auto-brightness? There's a few hours difference between your two screenshots. Try seeing if this issues comes and goes at different times of the day. If it does, consult [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376437/385841) for how to turn auto-brightness on and off.

Comment: Yes i hav disabled it!

Comment: And this was the first time i faced such issue I have been using dark mode since the day it rolled out

Comment: Auto-Brightness does not change according to the time of the day but according to the ambient brightness.

Answer (score 0):

### Not a bug

This is simply because the messages contain a "quote" which means that they are a reply to another message. Check out [How to reply to messages - WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/3240283752856917) for more info.

[image: Screenshot of WhatsApp messages in dark mode with quotes]

Also, in a message containing a quote, the reply background changes color slightly to contrast with the quote color (which is the normal message color).